# Find the list of procedures invoked from the main procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a main procedure in oracle which invokes many procedures inside it. These internal procedures also call functions and procedures inside it. This continues to many levels.
For ex:

```
Proc A

 call c

 call d

end............

proc c

 call e

 call f

end ....................

proc e

 call j

 call h

end
```

j calls some procedure which internally calls another and so on. This loop goes on and on.

I want to find the names of all procedures invoked at run time when main api is executed. Is it possible to find all of them using toad ? Is there any tool for doing this ?

Comment: Basically you would like to see which all procedures and functions or other objects are being used when you execute your main procedure right?

Comment: A bit useful link for you: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2430991

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a [code profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_profiling) tool ? For Oracle see `DBMS_PROFILER`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to recursively travel `user_dependencies`:

```
select * from user_dependencies 
start with name = 'MAIN_PROC' 
connect by name = prior referenced_name 
        and type = prior referenced_type
        and referenced_type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION' );
```

see a demo: ----> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ca2a/1

Answer (score 0):

You can check the name of the procedures/functions that are being used in the main procedure by using the dba_dependencies data dictionary view in oracle. However for checking at run time, you might have to write DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE statements or you can create a audit_log_table where you would insert the names of the procedures/functions.

Comment: HI, dba_dependencies is able to provide me only the procedures and packages that are directly referenced inside the main procedure.However what i need is all the procedures that can get called when i call the main  procedure which will also include the procs that are invoked from the referenced procs.

Comment: @njnbat you just have to travel `dba_dependecies` table _recursively_.

Answer (score 0):

In Schema Browser of Toad click on main procedure which you are executing and on the right side panel, there is a tab called **Deps (Used By)**. Under this you will find all the objects which are being used.

Alternatively you can do the following which will list all dependent objects

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  user_dependencies
 WHERE  name = '<your_procedure_name>' AND referenced_type='PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: dba_dependencies and user_dependencies have given me same result . it is not providing the procedures being invoked by the reference procedures inside the main api.Hence its not helping my cause.

Comment: Also Oracle's SQL Developer has similar feature.

Comment: @polppan yes i have tried deps (used by) in toad too. it is giving me only the api's directly referenced inside that procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I used Oracle **AUDIT** to trace which *functions/procedures/packages* are used by a client application (invoking them from client side). You could use it specifying particular plsql statement name, in your case your main procedure name, and trace them further. I think it could be some helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple query over metadata that gives what you want.  Here however are some areas you can do your own research in to find what you need.

1. Use PL/SCOPE.  This is an Oracle provided tool that when turned on, auto-magically collects detailed information about your pl/sql code every time you compile it, and stores this info in new Oracle dictionary tables.  You can thus write reports about the structure of your code, what queries it executes, etc.

http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2018/07/the-plscope-resource-center.html

2. Have a look at CLEARSQL from Conquest Software.  This is a pl/sql analyzer tool that also analyzes pl/sql code.  It produces great pictures and other artifacts to help you understand what your code is doing.  It is a great tool for doing code reviews of other people's code.  I will tell you now, there is nothing like heading into a code review with better documentation under your wing, than the developers who wrote the code have.  Used right this tool can make you a rock star for this activity.  This tool used to be real cheap, but they got wise as to the value of what they have.  Still worth it though.  This link is only one link to their tool set and subscription may not be the best pricing strategy for most people.

https://sqldev.tech/clearsql8_subscription

3. You can use DBMS_UTILITY routines: FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE and FORMAT_CALLSTACK inside your code to tell you where you are at.  Again I will refer you to Steven.

http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/o25plsql-093886.html

4. If you are really really desperate, you can have a look at DBMS_DEBUG but this ain't for beginners (not saying you area a beginner, just noting its skill requirements).

Good luck.  Kevin